# EKS CSR Signer kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver-client no certificate

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, certificate-signing-request

I recently upgraded an eks cluster from 1.18 to 1.21 in EKS. I had been using a CSR with apiVersion: `certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1`. This is deprecated from 1.19+, but still functional in 1.21. But will be removed in 1.22. I had been using signer kubernetes.io/legacy-unknown, which after issuing `kubectl certificate approve` would give a certificate under `kubectl get csr my-csr -n my-namespace -o jsonpath='{.status.certificate}`
I went on to update the apiVersion for the CSR to `certificates.k8s.io/v1` and use signer  `kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver-client` as per this [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/certificate-signing-requests). Although I am getting the CSR approved, there is no certificate. Can someone point me in the right direction regarding this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

EKS does not have a kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver-client signer. Instead they manage users via AWS IAM. This is a custom and EKS specific way to handle users.

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html